# adding variable to column entries awk

Tags: awk

I want to give a value from a file read to a variable, then use it to modify all elements of a column in another file, specifically to shift the entries by some number.

The data file "file_to_change" has two columns of numerical data, one to be shifted in value. Like so:

```
-1.643465E+01    1.378835E-03
-1.642464E+01    1.242392E-03
-1.641463E+01    1.147501E-03
-1.640462E+01    1.083067E-03
-1.639461E+01    1.042069E-03
-1.638460E+01    1.020041E-03
-1.637459E+01    1.014211E-03
```

The file "tmp" which contains the shifting value is simply this:

```
-11.43465
```

I current have the following code:

```
file=tmp
var1=$(awk 'NR==1' $file)

echo $var1

awk '{print ($1 - $var1) " " $2}' file_to_change

echo $var1
```

My result is:

```
   -11.43465
   0 1.378835E-03
   0 1.242392E-03
   0 1.147501E-03
   0 1.083067E-03
   0 1.042069E-03
   0 1.020041E-03
   0 1.014211E-03
   -11.43465
```

I imagine this is pretty straightforward, but I can't see where the error is!

Comment: You can't use shell variables in awk like that (`$var1`). You need to give it's value to awk variable like: `awk -v var1="$var1" '{ ... var1 ...`

Comment: You could pass a variable to awk from shell like this: `awk -v 'var1=value'  '{print ($1 - $var1) " " $2}' file_to_change`  (In awk you refer to the variable as var1 and not $var1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you're not passing the **shell** variable into awk correctly. The single quotes around the awk body are preventing shell variable expansion. And if you used double quotes around the awk body, then the shell will expand the **awk** variables "$1" and "$2".

You could do this quoting mess:

```
awk '{print ($1 - '"$var1"') " " $2}' file_to_change
```

Or the much cleaner

```
awk -v var="$var1" '{print ($1 - var) " " $2}' file_to_change
```

---

To explain why you get 0 in the first column: in awk, an unset variable is treated as an empty string or, if you're in a "numeric context", the number zero. You have `$var1` where the **awk** variable "var1" is not set. The `$` is a kind of operator, returning the value of the column number. So $1 is the value of the first column, $2 the value of the second column, etc. You can use variables there, so `x=14; print $x, $(x+1)` prints the 14th and 15th column. Since the `var1` variable is unset, the expression `$1 - $var1` becomes `$1 - $0` which becomes (for the first line):

```
"-1.643465E+01" - "-1.643465E+01    1.378835E-03"
```

When awk does arithmetic with strings, the first non-numeric character and following characters are simply dropped. To demonstrate:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {print "10foo" - "7bar"}'
3
$ awk 'BEGIN {print "1e1foo" + "-700e-2bar"}'
3
```

So,     `"-1.643465E+01" - "-1.643465E+01    1.378835E-03"`
becomes     `-1.643465E+01 - -1.643465E+01`
hence `0`

This can be easily reproduced:

```
$ seq 10 | paste - - | awk '{print $1 - $novar, $2}'
0 2
0 4
0 6
0 8
0 10
```

Comment: I'd write your code like: `awk -v var="$(< tmp)" '{$1 -= var} 1' file_to_change`

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it, you want to subtract value in file "tmp" from column 1 in file "file_to_change", right?

One way is this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{val=$0; nextfile} {$1-=val; print}' tmp file_to_change
```

First, we read the value from the first line of file "tmp" and skip to the next file.

For each line in "file_to_change" subtract the value from column 1 and print the resulting line.

The result is this:

```
-5 1.378835E-03
-4.98999 1.242392E-03
-4.97998 1.147501E-03
-4.96997 1.083067E-03
-4.95996 1.042069E-03
-4.94995 1.020041E-03
-4.93994 1.014211E-03
```

Comment: Note that `nextfile` is specific to GNU awk